# SQL select query not working with variable parameter in my servelets

Tags: sql, netbeans, jdbc

i'm trying to execute following line of code with my servelet in netbeans:

```
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from ZEE.WORDCOUNT where WORD =" + searchTxt);
```

where **searchTxt** is String variable.

but it says "Column 'zeeshan' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join . . . . ".

it really works fine, if i provide the hardcoded value instead of variable, as:

```
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from ZEE.WORDCOUNT where WORD= 'zeeshan'");
```

i'm not getting, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes around the sql string you are constructing. So this should work:

```
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from ZEE.WORDCOUNT where WORD ='" + searchTxt+"'");
```

Please note that constructing SQL statements in this way is really dangerous, because it opens your application up for SQL injection attacks. Use bind parameters instead.

This will also allow better caching of parsed statements on many rdbms's.

Comment: it was asking me to wait for 8 minutes :P thats why i did it late

Comment: @Zeeshan: you should be using a `PreparedStatement` instead.